# Where does go download my dependencies if I do not specify GOPATH?

Tags: go, go-modules

new go learner so this might be a trivial question. If I understand the documentation correctly, go had been using `GOPATH` in the beginning and every dependency and source code need to be in this GOPATH but after 1.1.1 GO switched gear to use Go Modules which is like other languages doing.

Now if I do not specify GOPATH at all in my bashrc/bash_profile or anywhere, I can now do `go init mymod` and write some code and simply run `go build` and it will download whatever depdendency package I am using without any problem. I have tried setting `GOPATH` and when `GOPATH` is set, the packages are downloaded to my GOPATH as expected, but without `GOPATH`, this still works. But I am not sure where the dependencies are downloaded.

Could you please explain to me what is happening here? Where the dependency pacakge are downloaded in this case?

Comment: "Where the dependency pacakge are downloaded in this case?" Still to GPATH with has a default. But it actually doesn't matter and could be different in the next version of Go. The go tool downloads and uses these dependencies transparantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [Command go: GOPATH environment variable:](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable)

> If the environment variable is unset, **GOPATH defaults to a subdirectory named "go" in the user's home directory** ($HOME/go on Unix, %USERPROFILE%\go on Windows), unless that directory holds a Go distribution. Run "go env GOPATH" to see the current GOPATH.